# OCIDate getting mangled on the way into Oracle

Tags: c, oracle, datetime, oracle-call-interface

I have some C code to populate an `OCIDate` from the epoch time:

In my main program:

```
OCIDate ocidate;
epoch_to_ocidate(c.f, &ocidate);
```

And in a library:

```
void epoch_to_ocidate(double d, OCIDate* ocidate) {
  time_t t = (time_t)d;
  struct tm *ut = localtime(&t); /* convert to a Unix time */

  OCIDateSetDate(ocidate, ut->tm_year + 1900, ut->tm_mon + 1, ut->tm_mday); 
  OCIDateSetTime(ocidate, ut->tm_hour + 1, ut->tm_min + 1, ut->tm_sec + 1);
}
```

I am pretty certain this is correct, because I have a check in the calling routine:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    char* fmt = "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS";
    ub4 dbufsize=255;
    debug("testing converted OCIDate:");
    OCIDateToText(h.err, (const OCIDate*)&ocidate, (text*)fmt, (ub1)strlen(fmt), (text*)0, (ub4)0, &dbufsize, (text*)dbuf);
    debug(dbuf);
#endif
```

And I am binding it with:

```
OCIBindByPos(s, &bh, h.err, (ub4)p, (dvoid*)&ocidate, (sb4)sizeof(ocidate), SQLT_ODT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

(`dbuf` is already defined). And that displays exactly what I would expect. But when it arrives in Oracle it's gibberish, resulting either in a nonsensical date (e.g. `65-JULY-7896 52:69:0` or a either ORA-1858 or ORA-1801). Has anyone seen anything like this before? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are actually binding the OCIDate object?

Comment: `sword x = OCIBindByPos(s, &bh, h.err, (ub4)p, (dvoid*)&ocidate, (sb4)sizeof(ocidate), SQLT_ODT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);`

Comment: s statement handle, bh bind handle, h.err error handle, p position, etc

Comment: Should your `sizeof` be referring to `OCIDate`, or `&ocidate`? Entirely possible I'm misreading that but it looks like it's sending the size of a pointer rather than the structure?

Comment: I wonder if it's because `ocidate` is a local variable and thus out of scope when I finally call `OCIStmtExecute()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it - the problem was that `ocidate` was stack allocated, and binding doesn't copy the value into the bindhandle, it merely sets a pointer, so when it went out of scope, that could have been pointing to anything. So I heap-allocated it instead. Now of course I have to bookkeep it, but I guess that's straightforward enough. Cheers!

Comment: Or you keep the stack-based OCIDate in-scope of the OCIStmtExecute(). This works for me. That way no explicit book-keeping.